# Inner Join with NamedQuery?

Tags: java, sql, inner-join, entitymanager, named-query

I need to get data from three different tables and into a list. I was wondering how I do it with namedQuery? I've seen that it's possible by searching online but I just can't get it to work.

```
SELECT
    Customer.name,
    Customer.adress,
    Orders.date,
    Orders.order_id,
    Product.product_name,
    Product.price
FROM
    Orders
    INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.customer_id=Orders.customer_id
    INNER JOIN Product ON Product.product_id=Orders.product_id
ORDER BY
    Orders.date
```

That's what I would want to convert to a namedQuery. It would be great if anyone could kick me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I'm unfamiliar with the term named query.
But this is how you would do it in SQL

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT
    Customer.name,
    Customer.adress,
    Orders.date,
    Orders.order_id,
    Product.product_name,
    Product.price
FROM
    Orders
    INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.customer_id=Orders.customer_id
    INNER JOIN Product ON Product.product_id=Orders.product_id
ORDER BY
    Orders.date
```

Then you can call it like so

```
SELECT * FROM view_name
```

Be warned though, views in views are terrible for performance.